# ROW NUMBER like 1 - 1.1 1.2 1.3 2 - 2.1 2.2 2.3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query like that.

```
SELECT 
    idn, barkod, ad, miqdar 
FROM
    (SELECT
         t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad, 
         SIUM(t2.nov * t2.miqdar) miqdar, 1 xus 
     FROM
         mallar t1
     LEFT JOIN  
         sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 ON t2.mal = t1.idn
     GROUP BY 
         t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
          t.idn, t1.barkod, 
          (SELECT adi FROM anbar WHERE idn = t2.anbar) + ' ' + t2.emel_name + ' ' + t2.sen_no, 
          t2.nov * t2.miqdar, 2 xus 
      FROM
          mallar t1
      LEFT JOIN 
          sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 ON t2.mal = t1.idn
     ) t
ORDER BY
    idn, xus
```

Result is something like that

```
1 1235143 Cigarette 5
1 1235143 Purchased 10
1 1235143 Selled    5
2 3453456 Cola      6
2 3453456 Purchased 6
```

But it must be like that

```
1    1235143 Cigarette 5
1.1  1235143 Purchased 10
1.2  1235143 Selled    5
2    3453456 Cola      6
2.1  3453456 Purchased 6
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Which database and which *version* are you using? All supported versions of SQL Server have `ROW_NUMBER()`. MySQL added this in v8.0.

Comment: Could an idn have an xus value of both 1 and 2?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an enumeration of each `idn` with the enumeration following a period -- except for the first value:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idn ORDER BY xus) > 1
             THEN CONCAT(idn, CONCAT('.', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idn ORDER BY xus) - 1)
             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), idn)
        END) as new_idn,
       idn, barkod, ad, miqdar 
FROM (SELECT t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad, sum(t2.nov*t2.miqdar) miqdar,1 xus 
      FROM mallar t1 LEFT JOIN
           sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 
           ON t2.mal = t1.idn
      GROUP BY t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t1.idn, t1.barkod, (SELECT adi from anbar where idn =t2.anbar)+' '+t2.emel_name+' '+t2.sen_no, t2.nov*t2.miqdar,2 xus 
      FROM mallar t1 LEFT JOIN
           sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 
           ON t2.mal = t1.idn
     ) t
ORDER BY idn, xus
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ordering in your outer query is by both (idn, xus) this code partitions the ROW_NUMBER by both (idn, xus).  Something like this

```
with mallar_cte as (
    (select t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad, 
            sium(t2.nov * t2.miqdar) miqdar, 1 xus 
     from  mallar t1
           left join sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 on t2.mal = t1.idn
     group by t1.idn, t1.barkod, t1.ad
     union all
     select t.idn, t1.barkod, 
            (select adi from anbar where idn = t2.anbar) + ' ' + t2.emel_name + ' ' + t2.sen_no, 
            t2.nov * t2.miqdar, 2 xus 
      from mallar t1
           left join sm_sob_qal_for_pr t2 on t2.mal = t1.idn)
with rn_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by idn, xus order by ad) rn
select concat(idn, (case when rn=1 then null else concat('.', rn-1) end)) idn,
       barkod, ad, miqdar 
from rn_cte
order by idn, xus, ad;
```